# How long usually is a Schengen short-stay C visa granted for?

Tags: schengen, pakistani-citizens, denmark

I am Pakistani national. I applied for a Schengen short-stay visa (single entry) in March 2017. I live in UK, my planned trip was very short, four days.

The Denmark Embassy gave me visa only for four days, the days I applied for (11-15).

Is it usual?

As far as I know, the duration of stay is usually granted more than the days applied for and the visa is valid for 90 days.

So, I am not sure why they gave me only four days' visa.

Does it work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it usual?

Less than the maximum 90 days in 180 is quite usual (per @Henning's Comment below - the norm for *single-entry* visas), though I suspect the full 90 days is more common (if considering both single and multiple entry visas). What is a little unusual is no margin - a few days is often rounded to a week or 11 days rounded to 15.

> Does it work this way?

Clearly it does. You got what you asked for. Had you asked for more you might have been allowed more but the chances of being granted a visa may have been a little less.

Comment: _Single-entry_ visas are usually issued only for the planned trip, plus a few days of grace in case force majeure prevents the traveler from leaving according to the original plan. (Since the Schengen rules require countries to extend visas free of charge if force majeure does happen anyway, adding this grace period is more a matter of administrative convenience for the host country than it's for the traveler's benefit).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it absolutely works this way; especially if this is your first time applying.

My very first Schengen visa was granted exactly for the duration of the stay as well.

The 90 days you mention is the *maximum allowed* (per 180 day period); but it is subject to your visa being granted for that length of time.

*Unlike the US and some other countries, a Schengen visa must be valid throughout the duration of the visit.*

Your visa is valid for exactly the dates and days mentioned on it.